# Keras layers explaination

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I want to get a deep idea about how this keras layers works in a model. What does each layer doing in the model etc. I followed kers documentation and information isn't enough. If any of you know place to get more knowledge let me know.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Keras layers are widely used CNN, DNN and RNN layers. There is atleast one research paper for each of them and there is a lot of educational material out there. If you are really curious you could look at keras' code. Some links for you:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/keras/layers

http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

https://leonardoaraujosantos.gitbooks.io/artificial-inteligence

http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a/srivastava14a.pdf